# Making a password search space calculator & Need help creating a function that creates a recursion based on a variable in (java) in html

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, passwords

Been making a brute force password search space calculator, I've gotten pretty far in it.
[Possible combinations] = [possible number of characters (To the Power of) The Password length]
and while everything seems to be in order. There's one more thing that i'd like to add that's been driving me crazy! trying to figure out how grc.com/haystack.htm is calculating their results because they do not match up with that algorithm at all. After awhile I finally figured out what they're doing and just need help writing the code. My end goal is to have a button to toggle between the normal algorithm and GRC's algorithm.

Math.pow(Charsetsize, PasswordLength) = ESSS,
Here's their "algorithm" in javascript:

1. **For Password Length of 1 they just do:**

- ESSS;

---

2. **For Password Length of 2 they do:**

- ESSS + Math.pow(Charsetsize, PasswordLength - 1);

---

3. **For Password Length of 3 they do:**

- ESSS + Math.pow(Charsetsize, PasswordLength - 1) + Math.pow(Charsetsize, PasswordLength - 2);

---

4. **For Password Length of 4 they do:**

- ESSS + Math.pow(Charsetsize, PasswordLength - 1) + Math.pow(Charsetsize, PasswordLength - 2) + Math.pow(Charsetsize, PasswordLength - 3);

---

5. **And so on in this recursion as the password length increases**

I need a function that can create that recursion based on the password length.

Comment: It's a recursion btw.

Comment: nameofmethod? I'm confused lol

Comment: So if I have a password length of n it will do n-1 n-2 until you only have 1 length and then do ESSS. I don't know what to do with less than 1 so I returned a 0.

Comment: function grc(len) {
 if(len < 1) return 0 ;
 if (len = 1) return window.ESSS; 
    return Math.pow(window.Charsetsize, len - 1) + nameofmethod(len - 1)
 } this just gives the same output as ESSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this to the value of grc.

```
function grc(len) 
{ 
  if(len < 1) 
  {
    return 0 ; 
  }
  if (len == 1)
  {
    return window.ESSS; 
  }
  return Math.pow(window.Charsetsize, len - 1) + grc(len - 1); 
}
console.log(grc(10));
```

Comment: So i did that. just for an example: charsetsize is 33 and length is 2. which 33 to the power of 2 is 1089 but grc should be:  ESSS + Math.pow(Charsetsize, PasswordLength - 1); which = 1122

Comment: your a life saver